# Budhist monastery rituals

Tags: meditation, rituals

I am not sure if I should ask this on this site and I apologise if I shouldn't. Just let me know and will be out of your hear. :D

I am going to go to South East Asia at the end of December and will stay there for about 5 months. I am really interested to see buddist ceremonies/festivals. I am from Romania (not a buddhist country) and there, in each region, monasteries have certain rituals which apply only for their region. I was wondering if there is anything like this in SEA as well? Or which are the rituals you would definitely want to go to? I would also like to go to monasteries where maybe you can join the muns for meditation for a day before moving on. I know you are supposed to do at least 7 days, but my partner is not really that into this type of things although he would have the patience of trying it for a day here and there. I am trying to ease him into it. :D

Please let me know what you think and again, if it was inaproprite for me to ask this here, I apologise.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Just to repeat what you asked, I think you're asking two questions: the second question is, "are there places (monasteries) where I can join in meditation for 1 day?"; and the first question is, "are there region-specific rituals, and/or rituals that you would want to go to?" in South East Asia.

Comment: You might (I don't know) also get some answer if you asked this question on [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe Singapore can be a good stop to visit many Buddhist Temples from different regions. There are

- [Thai Buddhist Temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sakya_Muni_Buddha_Gaya_Temple)
- [Burmese Buddhist Temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burmese_Buddhist_Temple)
- [Sri Lanka Buddhist temple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sri_Lankaramaya_Buddhist_Temple)
- [Buddha Tooth Relic Temple and Museum at ChinaTown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddha_Tooth_Relic_Temple_and_Museum)

For meditation, it might be quite difficult as you might need to join a group to mediate in a specific place or find a quiet place inside the temple to meditate.

If you are visiting Yangon in Myanmar/Burma Country, you should definitely visit [Shwedagon Pagoda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shwedagon_Pagoda). You can find a lot quite place to meditate and you might also see a large crowd celebrating [Buddhist festival](http://www.buddhanet.net/festival.htm) at Full-Moon day.